# The "back button" in the action bar on android 4.0.3 appears to crash my app

Tags: android, android-intent, crash, android-actionbar, android-logcat

## Edit

The problem that occurred was due to me setting the parent of the settings activity in the manifest to all lower case, which was not the correct format of the path to the main activity.

---

My initial goal of the app was to successfully implement a load and save button to (you guessed it) load and save data (to a text file on the external sd card).  After successfully implementing this feature, I decided to play around with Shared Preferences with the use of a settings file which would change to font size and color.  I set up a menu which would run my settings activity through an intent.  The settings activity was generated by the sdk, yet seems to crash after you press the back button on the action bar.  [Screenshots of the app](http://i.imgur.com/BcKza.png), [the logcat file](http://pastebin.com/fVZW6wNX), and my source code are below.  Thank you for your time!

---

**This is the method used to start the settings activity.**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

**This is the generated settings activity.**

```
package com.spacemanspiff.savefiles;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_settings, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

---

Comment: Please add your LogCat errors to you question, so we can see what is happening.

Comment: I've had issues with `navigateUpFromSameTask` before, I would honestly say just use `finish()` in this case.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but when you use `finish()` you insert it after you implement `startActivity(intent)` method.

Comment: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.spacemanspiff.savefiles/com.spacemanspiff.savefiles.mainactivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I'd go with Eric's suggestion, try just calling `finish()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
The crash can be rectified by adding the **android:parentActivityName** in the manifest    file for the child activity.
    E.g.


       <activity
            android:name="com.example.projectlearn.ActivityTwo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_two"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.projectlearn.MainActivity" >
        </activity>
```